# Is it possible to uniquely reconstruct a binary tree with just inorder traversal with null makers?

Tags: binary-tree, inorder

Is it possible to uniquely reconstruct a binary tree with just in-order traversal and null makers?

For example, for the tree:

```
  A
 / \
B   C
```

The inorder traversal with null markers is:
null, B, null, A, null, C, null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  A          C
 / \        / \
B   C      A   D
     \    /
      D  B
```

It seems these trees both gives: null, B, null, A, null C, null D, null.

But it's possible to save a binary tree of depth N in array of size 2<sup>N</sup>-1.

```
     A           C
   /   \       /   \
  B     C     A     D
 / \   / \   / \   / \
N   N N   D B   N N   N
```

null, B, null, A, C, null, D
B, A, null, C, D, null, null